# jQuery .css() not working in IE 7,8

Tags: jquery

I wanted to use this code for IE7

```
<!--[if IE 7]> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        (".contacts-table tr:even").css("background", "#dedede");
    })
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

but I got an error and it doesn't work.
What's wrong?

Comment: The `css()` jQuery function works absolutely fine in IE 7 & 8. Please look at your own code before blaming the tools.

Comment: I know `css()` jQuery function should work in IE 7 & 8. I got answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the `$`

```
$(".contacts-table tr:even").css("background", "#dedede");
```